# Restoring files names using md5 file

Tags: linux, files, hashsum

I recovered some files from my HDD, but there names were changed. Also, I found md5 files of the recovered files.

How can I use the md5 file to restore files names?

Answer (score 0):

First rename (or link) each recovered file to a name that contains its MD5.

Then loop over the file (perhaps using `while read md5 name`) and rename (or link) the md5name back to the original file name.

assuming the file is of the format produced by md5sum something like this will work.

```
for x in * 
do 
  mv "$x" `md5sum < "$x" | cut -d' ' -f1`
done

cat /elsewhere/md5file |
while read md5 name 
do
  mv "$md5" "$name"
done
```

be sure not to rename the MD5 list in the first step. I have assumend it's in the fictional location `/elsewhere/` you could put in your home or in /tmp/  etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try in one step:

```
md5sum * | awk 'NR==FNR {FN[$1] = $2; next} {print "mv -v \"" $2 "\" \"" FN[$1] "\""}' md5file -
```

This creates a md5sum signature for every file in your working directory, pipes it into an `awk` script that reads the "old" filenames from the old md5 file into an array indexed by the signature, then reads the actual file names from stdin (`-`, the pipe) and prints the respective `mv` command to stdout. Pipe this into a shell (`| sh`) if happy with what is proposed.

Comment: File name has white spaces

Comment: OK, add double quotes around both source and target file names.

Comment: It didn't work , and its just prints the file its not rename them

Comment: @C.ClaryChristion Read the last part of the answer again.